# VBA to find Install Date and Bios Date for remote machines

Tags: vba, shell, excel, wsh

I am trying to get some VBA code working to return a computers Ping result, Installation Date and BIOS Version (to get the date).

```
For i = 1 To lRow
Debug.Print i
addr1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value 'this contains my IP/Computer Name

cmdPing = "C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE " & addr1
Set shPing = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
Set runPing = shPing.exec(cmdPing)
strPing = runPing.stdout.readall
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = strPing
Set runPing = Nothing
Set shPing = Nothing

cmdInstall = "systeminfo /s " & addr1 & " | findstr /C:""Install Date"""
Set shInstall = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
Set runInstall = shInstall.exec(cmdInstall)
strInstall = runInstall.stdout.readall
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = strInstall
Set runInstall = Nothing
Set shInstall = Nothing

cmdBios = "systeminfo /s " & addr1 & " | findstr /C:""BIOS Version"""
Set shBios = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
Set runBios = shBios.exec(cmdBios)
strBios = runBios.stdout.readall
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = strBios
Set runBios = Nothing
Set shBios = Nothing

Next i
```

The Ping works fine, but the systeminfo flickers on briefly and disappears. I can run with just `"systeminfo /s " & addr1`, but obviously that brings through a lot of unnecessary info. I have a feeling it is to do with passing the `"` character. Have tried `/C:" & Chr(34) & "` to no avail as well.

Comment: Have also tried replacing the `|` with `Chr()` in case that was the issue. Was not sure which one directly correlated with that character, but tried 5, 124 and 166 but still did not work.

Comment: It's 124. Ran `i = 0: Do Until Chr(i) = "|": i = i + 1: Loop: Debug.Print i` to check.

Comment: yes `ASC("|") = CHR(124)` but that's not the problem. I am not sure why it does not work but what you can do is run just `"systeminfo /s " & addr1` once and then pull the Install date and the Bios version from the returned string using VBA

Comment: I didnt think it was either, but just posting it to clarify the first comment :)

Comment: Yeah I know I can pull the info from the full result (its what I did when running it this time) but would like to figure out how to get it working like this in future as the fact is it _should_ work ;)

Comment: Also, another point for clarity: I have tried replacing `systeminfo` with the full path which still makes no difference (you can see it firing up briefly anyway so was highly unlikely it would be that)

Comment: right, so if you run `Debug.Print runInstall.stderr.readall` it actually shows an error `ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '|'.
Type "SYSTEMINFO /?" for usage.` I think that for some reason the `findstr` is not being recognized

Comment: and there we go I found an answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/Z-Rmh6sOTSY)

Comment: Aha! Wouldnt have thought to invoke cmd beforehand. Nice find!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmdInstall = "%comspec% /c systeminfo /s " & addr1 & " | findstr /C:""Install Date"""
```

and

```
cmdBios = "%comspec% /c systeminfo /s " & addr1 & " " & Chr(124) & " findstr /C:""BIOS Version"""
```